# Angular5: Unable to get firebase object

Tags: angular, firebase

I just created a sample firebase object in firebase console, and I want to get the object in my typescrip. I followed the steps as in http://www.dotnetmob.com/angular-5-tutorial/angular-5-crud-operations-with-firebase/. But no luck. can anyone help me with this please?

Here is my object: 
   [image]

```
constructor(private db :AngularFireDatabase) {
    let item:any = db.list('OAuth');
    console.log("_____________", item);
}
```

What I'm missing. I'm getting the output in browser console like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can access the data by 
`item.stateChanges(["child_added"]).subscribe((data) => {
     var items = data.payload.val();
})`

Comment: It is not working. item.stateChanges(["refresh_token"]).payload gives undefined.

Comment: You've to use "child_added" not "refresh_token"

Comment: I'm sorry you've use:- `item.stateChanges(["child_added"]).subscribe((data) => { let items = data.payload.val(); });`

Comment: Sounds good. But what if I've more childs. Can I get by key? And, how can I update the refresh_token value?

Comment: Yes, you can get all the info by key. Just change the payload to key and you don't have to refresh this code to get the new values. It'll automatically bring the new values once added or made some changes to Database.

Comment: key gives only key name(Ex: refresh_token). I want something like, data['refresh_token'].

Comment: Then you've to use payload as I mentioned before and you can access the key from `data.payload.val().key`